# Multiple PHP str_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, title, str-replace

I would like to use two str_replace in my PHP echo. Below is my code: it displays my Wordpress post title, and replace the `|` by a `</br>` to make the title appearing on multiple lines. It works, but now I would like to add italic to few words of that same title. Does anybody have an idea how to manage this?

```
<?php echo str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); ?>
```

Comment: You could place the first `str_replace` to a variable, and then run another `str_replace` on that variable. Something like; `$first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); echo str_replace('REPLACE_ME', '<i>REPLACE_ME</i>', $first);`

Comment: Great! :-D
Do you actually know how to add three str_replace for same purpose? I just realized that the italic is open but doesn't stop, so it is applied to the rest of my text. Maybe I could use a replaced caracter that opens the italic and another that close it? I tried to do it like this, but I can't find the correct syntax.
Thanks!

Comment: That's why I was replacing the `REPLACE_ME` (which is the content you want to have inside a `<i></i>` tag) with the exact same content, just inside those tags^

Comment: I apologize, you are right! 
Thank you again :)

Comment: @Lolo can you close this question and mark an answer?

Comment: @Lolo can you close this question and mark an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something such as:

```
$string = str_replace([' | ', 'REPLACE_ME'], ['<br />', 'REPLACE_ME'], 'STR_TO_REPLACE');
```

This way you only need to call `str_replace` once but you can change many input values with many output values?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Jeppesen, it works perfectly!
I made a small correction, here is what solved my problem:

```
<?php 
  $first = str_replace(' | ', '<br />', get_the_title()); 
  echo str_replace('°', '<i />', $first);
?>
```